# Set item on navigation view as selected from fragment

Tags: android, android-navigationview

When moving to a different fragment I want the corresponding item in the navigation menu to be highlighted. This should be done from the fragment itself.
Below is the code present in the fragment:

```
  saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispName = dispNameET.getText().toString();
            myRef.setText(dispName);

            //going to another fragment
            Fragment fragment = new ListFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
    });
```

After this the navigation view shows wrong item as highlighted.
Please help

Comment: try navigationview.getMenu().getItem(youritemnumber).setChecked(true); inside click listener, where **youritemnumber** is the item position which you want to highlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should look like this

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dispName = dispNameET.getText().toString();
        myRef.setText(dispName);

        //going to another fragment
        Fragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id./*id of nav bar*/);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id./*id of menu item to be highlighted*/);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id./*id of nav bar*/);
 navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id./*id of menu item to be highlighted*/);
```

Put this code in the onClick method or in the beginning of required fragment